# What is a good way to form/store data which needs to be changed and called frequently in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to generate and store data for NPCs. This would include physical stats (how they look/combat capabilities) and mental traits (how they act).

I need the NPCs stats to be randomly generated and then stored for later use.
How would you go about doing this?

Is it possible to create a character generator then store the generated character in a object or alternative to recall at a later date either to change or use? How would I go about doing this?

Also if you know of any resources that I can learn from for this subject I would be grateful if you share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For along time ago, the problem like this encountered to me.
I used .txt file.
I stored and read states to "*.txt" file with "c#" library.
And then added generate random algorithm based on these data.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CCharacterInfo
{

    public class CDataRead
    {

        public FileStream m_file = null;

        FileInfo m_fileInfo = null;
        string m_fileName = "";
        bool m_fileOpened = false;

        public byte[] m_bDatabuffer;
        int m_nFilelength = 0;


        ~CDataRead() {
            if (m_fileOpened)
                m_file.Close();
        }

        public bool OpenFile(string fileName) {
            m_fileInfo = new FileInfo (fileName);
            if (!m_fileInfo.Exists) {
                m_fileInfo.Create ();
            }   

            m_file = m_fileInfo.OpenRead();
            m_fileName = fileName;
            m_fileOpened = true;

            if(m_file != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public string GetFileName() { return m_fileName; }

        public long GetFileSize() { return m_file.Length; }

        public void Seek(int nOffset) { m_file.Seek (nOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin); }

        public int ReadFile(byte[] buff, int nCount) {
            if (nCount == 0) return -1;

            int numBytesToRead = nCount;
            int numBytesRead = 0;
            while(numBytesToRead > 0) {
                // may return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.
                int n = m_file.Read(buff, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);

                if (n == 0) // break when the end of the file is reached.
                    break;

                numBytesRead += n;
                numBytesToRead -= n;
            }
            return numBytesRead;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I store my NPC in a class, which defines its attributes. When I create an NPC, I use a switch statement to load fixed stats into the class and return it. You could change this to a random generator to randomly modify stats.

This worked for me up to 100 npcs fixed, probably not the most "efficient" way to do it, but its up and running in 5 mins, needs no file access and is easily changed, added to or reworked!

```html
public class NPC
{
    public int NPC_ID;                    // the unique ID of the NPC
    public string Name;
    public bool active;
    public string SpriteName;
    public int PassiveAbility;            // The passive ability the NPC grants 0= none
    public int Dice_ID;                   // The Dice ID the NPC adds to the party 0=none
    public int HP;                        // Max hit points (fully healed)
    public int HPR;                       // Hit points remaining
    public int FP;                        // Max hit points (fully healed)
    public int FPR;                       // Hit points remaining
    public int MaxSlots;                  // Number of item slots  
    public bool Fem;                      // Use female audio  

    public NPC() { }  // Make a blank one

    public NPC(int ID)   // Pass the ID to create the NPC of that ID
    {
        NPC_ID = ID;
        HP = 2;
        PassiveAbility = 0;
        MaxSlots = 3;
        FP = 5;
        Fem = false;
        if (ID < 16) {              // The first 15 NPCs bring passives
            Dice_ID = 0;
        } else {                    // The last 15 NPCs bring Dice 
            Dice_ID = ID-15;
        }

        switch (ID)   // Only showing 7 here, but you could have hundreds
        {
            case 1:
            // my stats are fixed here, but you could randomly generate them here
                Name = "Bisky"; SpriteName = "N25"; PassiveAbility = 12; MaxSlots = 0; FP = 20; break;
            case 2:
                Name = "Zahid"; SpriteName = "N28"; PassiveAbility = 2; MaxSlots = 4; break;
            case 3:
                Name = "Anna"; SpriteName = "N17"; HP = 1; PassiveAbility = 3; FP = 8; Fem = true; break;
            case 4:
                Name = "Carl"; SpriteName = "N30"; PassiveAbility = 4; MaxSlots = 4; break;
            case 5:
                Name = "Max"; SpriteName = "N06"; PassiveAbility = 5; break;
            case 6:
                Name = "Alex"; SpriteName = "N04"; PassiveAbility = 6; break;
            case 7:
                Name = "Lincon"; SpriteName = "N11"; PassiveAbility = 11; break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

store to a .txt or .json file if you don't care about player being able to change the data or use a binary converter otherwise